# How to create Pivot table using C#?

Tags: c#, pivot-table

I need to create a pivot like this

```
                     BatchID-1        BatchID-2
                     BachName-1       BachName-2

Chemical-1             0.1                null
Chemical-2             null                0.3
```

BatchID,BatchName are columns of the Sql Server Table.
Here i need to display the value of specific chemical if Specific BatchID and BatchName

Can any one please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: I just write code for Normal pivot table.
I did not any code for this Pivot table.

Comment: Do you already have it in a "DataTable" object?  Is the data coming down from some SQL database... Where is its origin?

Comment: BatchId-1,BatchName-1 are Sql Database table columns

Answer (score 4):

I suggest leaning a bit of SQL, a bit of C# and a bit about pivot table. Then write some code. Preferably, make it compile.

Once you know all these things, you'll probably be able to ask a more precise question, such as "Using the Xxx Pivot control, I try to read data from SQL server using this SQL query and try to populate the data, but I encounter this specific issue..."

At that point, stackoverflow will probably be helpful in answering your question. Until then, I don't think anyone is going to give you the code you require, as writing code is probably what you should be doing yourself to learn (if student), grow (if amateur) or get paid (professional).

Answer (score 0):

Use a control such as [XtraPivotGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Pivot_Grid/) (DevExpress), or some free alternative

Comment: Can you please tell me those free alternatives?

Comment: They're just *hypothetical* free alternatives, I actually don't know any of them...

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure, or a LINQ statement.